# How I can use ^ and & in password when I pass jenkins url with parameter and calling with curl command

Tags: python, jenkins, passwords

I am trying to call as following by python script, I already imported all required libraries
I have command variable like following and function like following

---

```
def Start_Job(command):
    global job_start_date
    print("\n----------------- Run Command -----------------\n" + command)   
    job_start_date = datetime.now()
    print("\n job_start_date = " + str(job_start_date) + "\n")
    try:
        os.system(command)
        print("\n-------- Wait for 100 seconds ---------------------") 
        time.sleep(100)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in Start_Job [" , str(e) , "]")

command = 'curl --insecure -u admin:G^H&j8k9G^H&j8k9 "https://expert_solution.net.plm.eds.com/job/Amar/job/WaitingTest/buildWithParameters?token=simdevops&Machine_Name=iltlvinteg6"'

Start_Job(command)
```

---

When I call `Start_Job()` function, due to & in password it splited password in 2 parts, first one is j8k9G^H and second one is j8k9, so password cannot assign in correct way otherwise ^ is not very well handle in command.
Please anyone can give proper solution or share hint on this problem

First I tried  `urllib.parse.quote(pass_word)` for this this is not working.
also tried another techniques but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode these special characters using percent encoding.

In Python, you have to use the urllib.parse.quote function to properly encode the username and password before constructing the URL. If it did not work for you, it will not have done the function you need correctly.

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
import urllib.parse

def Start_Job(username, password, jenkins_url):
    global job_start_date
    # Encode the username and password
    encoded_username = urllib.parse.quote(username, safe='')
    encoded_password = urllib.parse.quote(password, safe='')

    # Construct the URL with encoded username and password
    url = f'https://{encoded_username}:{encoded_password}@{jenkins_url}'
    
    print("\n----------------- Run Command -----------------\n" + url)   
    job_start_date = datetime.now()
    print("\n job_start_date = " + str(job_start_date) + "\n")
    try:
        os.system(f'curl --insecure "{url}"')
        print("\n-------- Wait for 100 seconds ---------------------") 
        time.sleep(100)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in Start_Job [" , str(e) , "]")

# Define your Jenkins URL, username, and password
jenkins_url = "expert_solution.net.plm.eds.com/job/Amar/job/WaitingTest/buildWithParameters?token=simdevops&Machine_Name=iltlvinteg6"
username = "admin"
password = "G^H&j8k9"

# Call the Start_Job function with encoded credentials
Start_Job(username, password, jenkins_url)
```

The modification I have made to the code is: first I encode the username and password using urllib.parse.quote with the safe parameter set to an empty string to ensure that all special characters are encoded correctly. Next, I construct the URL with the encoded credentials, and the os.system call uses this URL for the command.

If you have any further issues or questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Julian, this worked partially but it help to me in other things.

Comment: That's good news! Even if I have partially helped you with your question, I have been able to solve other possible doubts. Thank you very much for appreciating my work!